# Is "the all" not correct?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Is the sentence B not correct and is only A valid? Or are the both ok?

A. I'd like to know **all the** problems we've had so far.
B. I'd like to know **the all** problems we've had so far.

Comment: Sentence A is correct, Sentence B is incorrect. I will leave the answer to those that can answer why with a good explanation!

Answer (score -1):

"All" is a determinative functioning usually as a predeterminer as in (A). In cannot be an adjective or function as an attributive modifier. Therefore, (B) is ungrammatical. However, you can use "whole", eg. "the whole problems".

Comment: You cannot use "the whole problems". "I'd like to know the whole problems we've had so far" is not correct.